# How to solve content overlapping into fixed header and footer with CSS for print

Tags: html, css, printing

[content is overlapping into fixed header and footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP1je.png)

I am trying to print a report with a fixed header and footer on every page.
Here is my CSS code:

```
@media print {

            table,
            div {
                box-sizing: border-box !important;
            }

            body {
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                background-color: lightpink;
            }

            @page {
                margin: 20mm
            }

            .printMainContainer {
                background-color: red;
                margin: 2% 3%;
                width: 94%;
                height: a;

            }

            .headerPart {
                width: 100%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: lightblue;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }

            .footerPart {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                height: 50px;
                background-color: lightblue;
                width: 100%;
            }

            table.reportTable {
                width: 98%;
                margin-top: 100px;
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }

            table.reportTable thead {
                display: table-header-group;
            }

            table.reportTable tfoot {
                display: table-footer-group;
            }
        }
```

When it goes into print preview, I saw my content overlap with the fixed header and also into the footer.
But I want to keep the same header and footer margin space on every page.